# How to set a Single Word in Bold in a Sentence Using pixi.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pixi.js

I am using a **PIXI.TEXT** object. I want to style a single word in a sentence with "font-weight bold".

```
this._richTextStyle = {
      fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      fill: ['#000000'],
      wordWrap: true,
      fontSize: 24,
      wordWrapWidth: 400
    };

    this._richText = new PIXI.Text('Hello world!', new PIXI.TextStyle(this._richTextStyle));
    this._richText.x = 10;
    this._richText.y = 40;
    this._textContainer.addChild(this._rectText);
```

I expect the output of 'Hello world!' to be 'Hello **world**!'

add plnkr url https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/RkLXnT93YqyLzRdM

Comment: Try this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixi-multistyle-text